# How to use ng-repeat in select angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have data like  this :

```
 $scope.data = [
    {
      }
]
```

How can i repeat it in select . I tried

```
 <select>
      <option  
      ng-repeat="d in data" value=" {{d.last_name.value}}{{d.first_name.value}}">
        {{d.last_name.value}}{{d.first_name.value}}
     </option>
    </select>
```

but not work . Here is plnkr : 
 http://plnkr.co/edit/GHSbBh9ddCiSFZZeKAQv?p=preview
Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inject $scope to your controller like this: `function ctrl($scope) {` 
 [Working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/A2tw9E?p=preview)